# Unable to scp from one EC2 instance to another EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am not able to scp from one EC2 instance to another EC2 instance. From my laptop I am able to ssh into each instance without issues.

I have two instances.

```
#worker1
ec2-107-20-7-57.compute-1.amazonaws.com

#master
ec2-50-19-8-109.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Here is what I have done so far.

I made a new key pair on the master node
    ssh-keygen -t dsa

I copy-and-pasted the id_dsa.pub from the master node to my laptop

```
scp -i ec2key.pem ubuntu@ec2-50-19-8-109.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa.pub /Users/me/somefolder
```

I copy-and-pasted the id_dsa.pub file from my laptop to the worker node

```
scp -i ec2key.pem /Users/me/somefolder/id_dsa.pub ubuntu@ec2-107-20-7-57.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/ubuntu/.ssh
```

On the worker node I appended the id_dsa.pub file to my authorized_keys file

```
cat id_dsa.pub >> authorized_keys
```

I created a file on the master node: /home/ubuntu/test.txt and then tried to scp this file from the master node to the worker node

```
scp -v -i ubuntu@ec2-50-19-8-109.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa ubuntu@ec2-50-19-8-109.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/ubuntu/test.txt ubuntu@ec2-107-20-7-57.compute-1.amazonaws.com:
```

I got the following result

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Any ideas?

Additional details:

- I'm using a Mac.
- The end goal is to set up a Beowulf cluster similar to what is mentioned here: http://techtinkering.com/2009/12/02/setting-up-a-beowulf-cluster-using-open-mpi-on-linux/

Comment: What are the permissions of ~ubuntu, ~ubuntu/.ssh, and ~ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys on ec2-107-20-7-57.compute-1.amazonaws.com. You can get it via ls -ld ~ubuntu.

Comment: Are you running the final scp from your mac? What happens if you use the ec2key.pem for the final scp? I don't think -i allows use of a remote private key, so you would either need to use the ec2key.pem, or copy the ubuntu@ec2-50-19-8-109.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa private key to your local system.

Comment: Check /var/log/secure on the target host to see why it's rejecting the keys.

Comment: @becomingwisest The permissions output for ~ubuntu is drwxr-xr-x, drwx------ for ~ubuntu/.ssh, and -rw------- for ~ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys.

Comment: @becomingwisest I'm running the final command from the master node. I tried running the command from my Mac instead, using scp -i ec2key.pem, but that also gave me a permission denied response. I'd like to be able to issue the command from the master node because in the future I would like to write a script to move stuff around while my Mac is not involved.

Comment: from the master, try scp -v -i /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa /home/ubuntu/test.txt ubuntu@ec2-107-20-7-57.compute-1.amazonaws.com: If that does not work, how about the contents of ~ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_key of the worker instance?

Comment: @becomingwisest Your suggestion worked. If you want to write that as an answer, I'll up-vote it and give it the check of approval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scp can't take a key from another server, even if that other server is the one you are on. Use a file system path to the identity file you want to use, if scp won't pick it up automatically.

scp -v -i /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa /home/ubuntu/test.txt ubuntu@ec2-107-20-7-57.compute-1.amazonaws.com:

or
 scp -v -i /home/ubuntu/test.txt ubuntu@ec2-107-20-7-57.compute-1.amazonaws.com:

Comment: I'm having trouble accessing the site through my phone. I'll upvote it too when I get to a computer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ssh-copy-id` to ensure that the key is copied correctly and that permissions on the relevant files/directories are correct.

If your system doesn't include the command `ssh-copy-id` you can get it from the following openssh repo. [openssh project repo](http://hg.mindrot.org/openssh/) & [link to openssh-copy-id](http://hg.mindrot.org/openssh/file/4bfd897331f6/contrib/ssh-copy-id)

Comment: This wouldn't overwrite the worker instance's existing public key (ie authorized_keys) file?

Comment: ssh-copy-id should be non-destructive, just adds to the authorized_keys file.

Comment: You can try using ssh -v or ssh -vv for more info.

Comment: I tried it but got a "command not found" response. I did some additional research and it looks like the ssh-copy-id command does not exist on Macs. I'm using a Mac.

Comment: See my edit to this question, i've included a link to the ssh-copy-id script for distros that are lacking it.

Comment: I'm still a bit new to Linux/Ubuntu -- what commands should I run to get and install the ssh-copy-id script? Or I guess I should be installing it on my Mac, right? I bet the Unix/Mac command is similar. Would you happen to know what commands to run on the Mac to obtain/install the script?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to setup new keys for this task.

If you are able to login from your mac, to both the machines, then I believe your keys are already setup.

You simply need to use this command:

```
# scp $master:<file> $worker:<file>
```

and this command will simply work out of the box.

ThoughI would still love to understand why you are creating new keys for this task.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and got another "Permission denied (public key)" response. I then tried doing a scp -i mypemkey.pem variation and still got the permission denied response.

Comment: The end goal is to set up a Beowulf cluster similar to what is mentioned here: http://techtinkering.com/2009/12/02/setting-up-a-beowulf-cluster-using-open-mpi-on-linux/. I'm a bit new to servers, linux, Ubuntu, and setting up a cluster for parallel computing in EC2, so I tried to follow everything in the tutorial as closely as possible. Like you mention, I too wouldn't be surprised if use of the preexisting EC2 keys were somehow possible. I'm just not confident enough with all of the material to know that it wouldn't mess up something in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to check your security groups! I spent a few hours quadruple-checking settings in ~/.ssh, instance id, dns name, reading all sorts of tutorials when it turned out I had just forgotten I'd set my instance to a security group only allowing a single IP address. Once I fixed that, it was just a matter of copying keys and setting things up as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to do one thing open the sshd_config file and edit the line PasswordAuthentication no 
to
PasswordAuthentication yes
Then set the password for the user using passwd command and restart the service.